# sort by drag and drop list with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

### [image: Heading]

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>            
    </head>
<style>
    #sortable{ list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
    #sortable li, #sortable2 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; width: 250px; }
    .wrp {font-size:12px;}
    #sortable {background:red;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="wrp">
<ol id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
        <li id="0"><div>Start</div>
        <li id="1"><div>TOC</div>
        </li>
            <li id="2">
                <div>Category1</div>
                        <ol id="category" class="category">
                            <li id="3"><div>Sub-category1.1</div>
                            </li><li id="4" ><div>Sub-category1.2</div>
                                    <ol id="sub_category" class="sub_category">
                                        <li id="5" class="item">Item1.2.1</li>
                                        <li id="6" class="item">Item1.2.2</li>
                                    </ol>
                            </li><li id="7"><div>Sub-category1.3</div>
                            </li><li id="8"><div>Sub-category1.4</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>    
            </li>    
    </li></ol>
</div> 
</body>

<script>
 $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        });

        $( "#category" ).sortable();
        $( "#sub_category" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".category"
        });

});
</script>
```

Currently I can :

- Move category in the same level
- Move sub category
- When a category or subcategory is moved, all of its   item are moved with it.
- Move Item in the same level

Could any give me a trick? How can I modified code that:
    - can move item to other category?
    example:
               I can move `item1.2.1` to `sub-category1.1`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but you may have luck trying:

```
$('#category').append($('#sub_category'));
```

I know the item will move, but am unsure about its children. You may have to loop through the children, moving them as you go. Or this may be totally off from what you were wanting.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the sub-items in sub-category1.2 are all wrapped in the same li tag. Also, why are you using such an old version of javascript?